# Can we add text on icon at run time in iphone?

Tags: ios

I am developing one application which is calendar based. I need to add today's date on application icon.

For example in the iPhone default calendar application, it dynamically changes its icon text day by day.

Can we do this using iphone sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of May 2012 this is still on the ["wishlist"](http://www.theverge.com/2012/5/12/3016671/ios-6-dynamic-app-icons-would-solve-a-lot-of-issues).  I believe that the Apple Calendar app has a dynamic icon because it is made by Apple.  An unfair advantage in the calendar market for sure ;)

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone calendar app uses private API to change its icon. Apple can do that; third-party developers (in the App Store, at least) can't.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.

However many developers in the past have requested this feature on Radar(including me).
The original enhancement request is being trcked with the Radar ID **5872097**.

If you wish to see the feature in future iOS sdks, raise your own request on [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this just you need to update that image on any server you are using.then you need to replace your icon.png image with the new one i u get from your server location.it